# Viewbox TabControl sizing gets messed up depending on font size

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I have a program that lets you edit different properties so that you can edit a different control.

I'm trying to get the layout right for the editor but I can't seem to get it easily.

I have put it in a viewbox so it sizes according to the screen. This is the XAML for the editor:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TabControl Background="{DynamicResource CustomOrange}">
        <TabItem Header="Background" Visibility="Visible" FontSize="10">
            <StackPanel>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                    <Label Content="Background" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Margin="2">
                    <Label Content="Background Image" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                    <Button Content="Find Image" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Margin="2">
                    <Label Content="Show Text" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                    <CheckBox Content="Find Image" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Button"  Visibility="Visible">
            <StackPanel>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                    <Label Content="Background IMAGE" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Margin="2">
                    <Label Content="Background Image" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                    <Button Content="Find Image" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Margin="2">
                    <Label Content="Show Text" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                    <CheckBox Content="Find Image" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Viewbox>
```

The problem is that the first TabItem looks like this:
[image: Background Tab Item]

But because I have changed the content of the label, the second TabItem looks like this:
[image: Button Tab Item]

Now, I know there are simpler ways to do this, but the problem is I don't know for sure how many options I am implementing for the user (Width, Height, Location, Font, Background, Content etc).

I have done it before with a grid but the problem is anytime I remove an option then all of them need to be re-done so that they are all in the exact Grid.Row which is why I am using StackPanel for the rows, and I am using the DockPanel so they keep separated horizontally

Thank you!!!

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: It doesn't appear that a ViewBox is at all suitable as a parent for a TabControl. Maybe put the content of each tab item in a ViewBox? I'm not convinced a ViewBox is ever suitable as a parent for anything other than pure graphics, though. I can't recall that being regarded as a conventional UI design thing anywhere later than like, 1990.

Comment: I'm trying to have the UI scale when the window gets resized. Seems like there is no easy or neat way to do that with a viewbox, I'll remove it.